# Как можно передать значения ширины и высоты, которые высчитываются в другом классе в custom view?

Tags: android, kotlin, customview

Проблема заключается в том, что `width` и `height` моего custom view высчитываются в другом вспомогательном классе `ChapterAdapter`. Мне нужно передать эти переменные в custom view и использовать для функции `onMeasure()`.

```
lateinit var chapterAdapter:ChapterAdapter
 //some code 
 override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        setMeasuredDimension(chapterAdapter.width, chapterAdapter.height)
 }
```

Я передаю объект класса `ChapterAdapter` в моем `Activity`
Это выглядит примерно так

```
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // some code
        chapterAdapter = ChapterAdapter()
        customView.chapterAdapter = chapterAdapter
        customView.invalidate()
    }
```

Если с прорисовкой проблем нет, благодаря вызову `customView.invalidate()`, то судя по жизненному цилку `View` функция `onMeasure()` вызывается раньше функции `onDraw()`. И в этом вся проблема, потому что тогда ширина и высота custom view просто не высчитываются и в итоге просто равны 0. Очевидным решением было бы реализовать функции расчета ширины и высоты прямо в кастомной вьшке, но это, к сожалению, невозможно, потому что придется полностью менять архитектуру приложения и этто приведет к смешению логики.

Comment: "`onMeasure()` вызывается раньше функции `onDraw()`" - это же логично: прежде чем рисовать, должна быть определена область рисования. Если вам это мешает, то у вас архитектура кривая. Попробуйте у `CustomView` вызвать `requestLayout()`, `forceLayout()`. Если не поможет ни то, ни другое, то исправляйте логику так, чтобы на момент их вызова размеры в `ChapterAdapter` уже были высчитаны.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onMesure -> layout -> onDraw

Все логично. Если вкратце, то первым методом View говорит родителю какого размера она хочет быть, вторым родитель сообщает дитю какого размера оно в итоге будет, последний отрисовывает содержимое с учетом полученного ранее размера. Если вызывать invalidate - отработает только onDraw. Если вы хотите пересчитать положения/размеры - вызывайте requestLayout, нередко его надо вызывать для родительского элемента

Я бы посоветовал создать свой кастомный ViewGroup, который будет иметь ссылку на адаптер и перегрузить для него layout, внутри которого сообщать вашим CustomView размеры с учетом данных из адаптера